# Replace multiple occurrences between two strings

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I need to replace **every** character `a` between `xx` and `zz` with `hello`:

```
#input
a xxab abzz ca xxbczz aaa axxazza xxczzaxxczz
#output
a xxhellob hellobzz ca xxbczz aaa axxhellozza xxczzaxxczz
```

This works for one pair, it doesn't work for more `xx/zz` pairs (it replaces every `a` between the first `xx` and last `zz`):

```
sed -r ':rep; s/(xx.*)a(.*zz)/\1hello\2/; trep'
```

---

I assume the best approach is to use more advanced regex, such as `perl`.

I am looking for a solution in `bash`, `sed`, `awk` or `perl`. Is this task even possible with basic/extended regex? Solutions that will not become hard to digest when the pairs have more characters (for example `xxxxxx/zzzzzz`) are preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's best to use Perl

```
perl -pe's/xx(.+?)zz/"xx".$1=~s|a|hello|gr."zz"/ge' file.txt
```

Comment: I had a hard time choosing of all the great solutions here. This one makes the most sense to me with my limited `perl` knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: @PesaThe I'm not downvoted. Hope, there is no explanation in the answer or the answer is same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105521/replace-multiple-occurrences-between-two-strings/48108606#48108606) answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this Perl method

```
perl -E '$_="a xxab abzz ca xxbczz aaa axxazza xxczzaxxczz";
s{xx(.+?)zz}{"xx".$1=~s/a/hello/gr."zz"}xge; 
say $_ ; '
```

Explanation

```
s{
   xx(.+?)zz #grouping the content
 }
 {
   "xx".$1=~s/a/hello/gr."zz" #again making the substitution for $1 and concatenating `xx` and `zz`  
 }xge;
```

Flags

`g` -> global

`r` -> non destructive modifier

`e` -> eval.

with look arounds

```
perl -E '$_="a xxab abzz ca xxbczz aaa axxazza xxczzaxxczz";
s{(?<=xx)(.+?)(?=zz)}{$1=~s/a/hello/gr}xge; 
say $_ ; '
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/zz/\n/;:b;tb;s/(xx[^\na]*)a([^\n]*\n)/\1hello\2/;tb;/zz/ba;s/\n/zz/g' file
```

This replaces `zz` with newline and then replaces any `a`'s between `xx` and a newline with `hello`.

N.B. It is possible to have any number of `xx` that are not paired with `zz` and any `a`'s between them will be substituted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach, if nothing else for comparison with a one-line regex that uses a somewhat more advanced regex feature (`/e` modifier, as in [mkHun answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48108606/4653379)).

Split the string by `xx`. Iterate over terms and replace `a` in each term's part up to `zz`, if there is `zz` in that term.  Reassemble (join back) the string.

I replace `a` to `-` for easy reviewing. The begin and end patterns are in `$pb` and `$pe`

```
perl -wE'
    $_ = shift // q(a xxab abzz ca xxbczz aaa axxazza); 
    say; 
    $pb = qr/xx/; $pe = qr/zz/;
    
    ($s, @t) = split /($pb)/; 

    for (@t) { 
        next if /^$pb$/; 
        next if not @m = /(.+?) ($pe.*)/x; 

        $_ = $m[0] =~ s/a/-/gr . $m[1] 
    }; 
    say $s . join "", @t
'
```

Comments

- Can test with other strings by submitting on the command line, `perl -wE'...' string`
- I use [qr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) to assign patterns that begin and end the section of interest in case they are more complex and need a regex.
- The capturing parens in split's separator pattern (`/($pb)/`) make it return the separator, as well, in its place along with other parts
- In each term we need both `zz` (or there is no `xx ... zz` so no replacement), and something before `zz` (or there is no need to do anything)
- The `zz` can be followed by more text, up to the next `xx` (on which we split)
- Elements of the array with terms are changed in place (by assigning to `$_`)

This is in a form that is ready to run as a command-line program, but it should be a script. It prints (comments added)

```
a xxab abzz ca xxbczz aaa axxazza    # original string
a xx-b -bzz ca xxbczz aaa axx-zza    # with replacements
```

I've tested with a few more strings but by all means please test more.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the `.*` as `.` will match every character including white space.
You should use `\S` instead as it will match all non-white space characters:

```
$ echo 'a xxababzz ca xxbczz aaa axxazza' | sed -r ':rep; s/(xx\S*?)a(\S*?zz)/\1hello\2/; trep'
a xxhellobhellobzz ca xxbczz aaa axxhellozza
```

Comment: I didn't provide good enough input, sorry. There can be any character between `xx/zz`, including whitespace.

Comment: Also, this won't work properly if there are more pairs in one "word": `'b xxczzaxxczz b'`.

Comment: Can you explain it? What all the options & `:rep;` & `trep` & the search/replace 1 & 2 are & how they interact?

Comment: @Xen2050 `\1` references the first captured group `( regex )`. `:rep` is a label, `t rep` is a command that jumps to label `rep` **ONLY** if any of the `sed` commands changed the patter space. The space is not mandatory: `trep`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to describe all that isn't `zz` *(a character that isn't a `z` or a `z` followed by an other character)* before and after the `a` until the `zz` and to use a label and a conditional test to process the line until there is no more `a` between `xx` and `zz` :

```
sed -E ':a;s/(xx([^z]|z[^z])*z?)a(([^z]|z[^z])*zz)/\1hello\3/g;ta' file
```

---

A Perl way:

```
perl -pe's/(?:\G(?!^)|xx(?=.*zz))[^za]*(?:z(?!z)[^za]*)*\Ka/hello/g' file
```

that can be easily changed to:

```
perl -pe's/(?:\G(?!^)|xxxxxx(?=.*zzzzzz))[^za]*(?:z(?!zzzzz)[^za]*)*\Ka/hello/g' file
```

to deal with `xxxxxx` and `zzzzzz`

Comment: This works great. However, is there a solution that won't get extra ugly when the pairs have more characters, for example: `xxxxxx/zzzzzz`?

Comment: It's obviously possible to write a replacement pattern in the same way even if this one is long with sed. If you want something shorter, use Perl.

Comment: Feel free to downvote my answer, I like that since I don't make a reputation competition.

Comment: It wasn't me, if you are implying that :)

Comment: @PesaThe: Don't worry of that, I know.

Comment: This does not appear to work if the input is  'xxzazz'