# Replace within capture group using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace

I'm trying to use word2vec in some text that contains phrase delimitations like

```
I <phrase>like green beans</phrase> in my tortillas.
```

Before feeding the text to word2vec I need the input to be:

```
I __like_green_beans__ in my tortillas.
```

I've been trying to use *sed* to do the replacement. By doing

```
sed -e 's@<phrase>\(.*\)</phrase>@__\1__@g' myfile.txt
```

I can get rid of the  delimiter but I haven't found a way to replace the spaces within the capture group.

Any ideas if it is possible with *sed*?

Comment: This might be useful: [Replace multiple occurrences between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105521/replace-multiple-occurrences-between-two-strings).

Comment: Thanks @PesaThe, I was able to get the result I wanted using the perl way described in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this sed

```
sed -E ':A;s/(>[^ ]*) ([^<]*<)/\1_\2/;tA;s/<[/]*phrase>/__/g'
```

Comment: Not sure how this is gonna scale when running it in my entire text corpus but it gets the job done. Thanks :)

Comment: For reference, this usage depends on GNU sed. For other variants of sed (notably the ones in BSD, macOS), you may need to separate this into multiple script segments, like this: `sed -E -e ':A' -e 's/(>[^ ]*) ([^<]*<)/\1_\2/;tA' -e 's/<[/]*phrase>/__/g'`

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu-awk`:

```
awk -v ORS= -v RS='<phrase>.*</phrase>' '1;
RT{gsub(/<\/?phrase>/, "___", RT); gsub(/ /, "_", RT); print RT}' file

I ___like_green_beans___ in my tortillas.
```