# RegEx match all occurrences inside specific string

Tags: python, regex

I try to match a specific string: `\slash` only inside a given substring (in this case inside  `\lstinline{}` confined by brackets):

```
lorem \lstinline{Foo\slash Bar\slash Foo} ipsum but \slash here is okay
```

desired output is `lorem \lstinline{Foo Bar Foo} ipsum but \slash here is okay`. See https://regex101.com/r/UgKvps/1

RegEx Flavour could be Python or any other really.

Comment: Here is a [Perl variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105521/replace-multiple-occurrences-between-two-strings)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! I don‘t understand it but this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking of `Python`, you could use the newer `regex` module which supports `\G` and `\K`:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'(?:\G(?!\A)|\\lstinline\{)[^{}]*?\K\\slash')

latex = "lorem \lstinline{Foo\slash Bar\slash Foo} ipsum but \slash here is okay"
latex = rx.sub('', latex)

print(latex)
```

This yields

```
lorem \lstinline{Foo Bar Foo} ipsum but \slash here is okay
```

Note that this won't work with nested latex commands (e.g. `\textbf{...}`).
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mRajix/1).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know of https://pypi.org/project/regex/ !

Comment: @karkraeg: Brilliant module - worth looking into, really.